# Getting ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-php

I'm using Google App Engine Flexible and some kind of rolling restart happened last night and my instance failed right after.

Looking at logs, I see this on new instance creation:

ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED

This appears to be related to this:

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/18012

But the status shows fixed and I'm still having issues.

Comment: Quite a lot of people are having issues, check Google's Issue Tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
and

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=timed%20out%20waiting%20for%20the%20app%20infrastructure%20to%20become%20healthy

Apparently many (if not all) regions are affected. Google says they are working on it, but I have not seen any updates within the last few days. Moving to a different region or zone does not seem to help since - as I said - many regions are affected.

Comment: My microservices on nodejs have been standing since November 5, 2018. I can not upload any version.